# Sharing meeting rooms/resources across different organizations

Tags: exchange, calendar, google-workspace, google-calendar

My company is sharing an office building with a completely different company.

We use Google Workspace, having our meeting room as "resources" in there.

The other company is using Exchange.

We're looking for a simple way to share meeting rooms with each other, so we don't book them at the same time.

Is there any good solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not know much about Gmail but I do found some information like "Turn on Exchange resource booking for your Google domain", please check [Allow Calendar users to book Exchange resources and see if it could help](https://support.google.com/a/answer/9193836?hl=en#zippy=%2Cstep-turn-on-exchange-resource-booking-for-your-domain).

Besides, from Exchange side, if they are using O365 email accounts, [Sharing Office 365 Room's availability to external users](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/outlook-blog/sharing-office-365-room-s-availability-to-external-users/ba-p/178054) should be able to help.

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Thanks for your understanding and support.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, it was helpful, I was waiting to see if more responses came in. In the end we went with using the second company's Office 365 external sharing capability.